# Minimize docker image with python and R

Tags: python, r, linux, docker, ubuntu

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip

# Setup the Python's configs
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir matplotlib==3.0.2 pandas==0.23.4 numpy==1.16.3 && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir pybase64 && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir scipy && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir dask[complete] && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir dash==1.6.1 dash-core-components==1.5.1 dash-bootstrap-components==0.7.1 dash-html-components==1.0.2 dash-table==4.5.1 dash-daq==0.2.2 && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir plotly && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir adjustText && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir networkx && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir scikit-learn && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir tzlocal

# Setup the R configs
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
RUN apt update
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
RUN apt install -y r-base
RUN pip install rpy2==2.9.4
RUN apt-get -y install libxml2 libxml2-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libssl-dev
RUN echo "r <- getOption('repos'); r['CRAN'] <- 'https://cran.r-project.org'; options(repos = r);" > ~/.Rprofile
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('BiocManager')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('ggplot2')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('DESeq2')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('RColorBrewer')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('ggrepel')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('factoextra')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('FactoMineR')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('apeglm')"

WORKDIR /
# Copy all the necessary files of the app to the container
COPY ./ ./

# Install the slider-input component
WORKDIR /slider_input
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir slider_input-0.0.1.tar.gz

WORKDIR /
EXPOSE 8050

# Launch the app
CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

It's used for running dash app that using R commands, and it works fine.
The problem is the size of the image.
I want to minimize the size of the image as minimal as possible, but everything I tried was unsuccessful because of the combination of python and R.

Do you have any idea how can I minimize this image, and provide the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Use [docker-slim](https://github.com/docker-slim/docker-slim) to minimize and secure your docker images. docker-slim will profile your docker image and throw away what you don't need.

It has been used with Node.js, Python, Ruby, Java, Golang, Rust, Elixir and PHP (some app types) running on Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS, Alpine and even Distroless.

docker-slim is production ready, but consider testing your container before deploying it to production. Minify docker images by up to 30x while making it secure too!

Comment: I tried using this tool, and it created the slim image, but when I try running this image it's seems that the last command (the one that launch the web app) is not running, do you have any suggestion why this is happened?

Comment: Without more details, my guess are limited. Have you tried running the command manually? `docker run image:latest "python app.py"`?

Comment: Yes, it give me the following error: ```docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"python ./bisek_app.py\": stat python ./bisek_app.py: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled```

Answer (score 0):

A multi-stage build will allow you to omit the compiler toolchain, headers, etc.. from the final image, only including the resulting code.

A three-part tutorial for Python specifically starts here: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/smaller-python-docker-images/

And the generic Docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/